# having some issues when i am compiling my code

Tags: c++, opengl

i really do not know why i am having these compiling issues here when i compiled this program yesterday it compiled nicely but today its not,the code shows how ro create shapes a ball and a cone and map their shadows im getting these errors

```
1>c:\users\soft\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cows\cows\www.cpp(125): error C2065: 'RgbImage' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\soft\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cows\cows\www.cpp(125): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'theTexMap'
1>c:\users\soft\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cows\cows\www.cpp(125): error C3861: 'theTexMap': identifier not found
1>c:\users\soft\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cows\cows\www.cpp(126): error C2065: 'texture' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\soft\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cows\cows\www.cpp(127): error C2065: 'texture' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\soft\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cows\cows\www.cpp(135): error C2065: 'theTexMap' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\soft\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cows\cows\www.cpp(135): error C2228: left of '.GetNumCols' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>c:\users\soft\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cows\cows\www.cpp(135): error C2065: 'theTexMap' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\soft\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cows\cows\www.cpp(135): error C2228: left of '.GetNumRows' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>c:\users\soft\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cows\cows\www.cpp(135): error C2065: 'theTexMap' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\soft\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cows\cows\www.cpp(135): error C2228: left of '.ImageData' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
```

and this is my code sorry i will just paste everything

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <math.h>
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
#include <GL/glut.h>


 GLfloat *make_texture(int maxs, int maxt)
{
    int s, t;
    static GLfloat *texture;

    texture = (GLfloat *)malloc(maxs * maxt * sizeof(GLfloat));
    for(t = 0; t < maxt; t++) {
        for(s = 0; s < maxs; s++) {
            texture[s + maxs * t] = ((s >> 4) & 0x1) ^ ((t >> 4) & 0x1);
        }
    }
    return texture;
}

enum {SPHERE = 1, CONE, LIGHT, LEFTWALL, FLOOR};


/* create a matrix that will project the desired shadow */
void shadowmatrix(GLfloat shadowMat[4][4],
             GLfloat groundplane[4],
             GLfloat lightpos[4]){
  GLfloat dot;

  /* find dot product between light position vector and ground plane normal */
  dot = groundplane[0] * lightpos[0] +
        groundplane[1] * lightpos[1] +
        groundplane[2] * lightpos[2] +
        groundplane[3] * lightpos[3];

  shadowMat[0][0] = dot - lightpos[0] * groundplane[0];
  shadowMat[1][0] = 0.f - lightpos[0] * groundplane[1];
  shadowMat[2][0] = 0.f - lightpos[0] * groundplane[2];
  shadowMat[3][0] = 0.f - lightpos[0] * groundplane[3];

  shadowMat[0][1] = 0.f - lightpos[1] * groundplane[0];
  shadowMat[1][1] = dot - lightpos[1] * groundplane[1];
  shadowMat[2][1] = 0.f - lightpos[1] * groundplane[2];
  shadowMat[3][1] = 0.f - lightpos[1] * groundplane[3];

  shadowMat[0][2] = 0.f - lightpos[2] * groundplane[0];
  shadowMat[1][2] = 0.f - lightpos[2] * groundplane[1];
  shadowMat[2][2] = dot - lightpos[2] * groundplane[2];
  shadowMat[3][2] = 0.f - lightpos[2] * groundplane[3];

  shadowMat[0][3] = 0.f - lightpos[3] * groundplane[0];
  shadowMat[1][3] = 0.f - lightpos[3] * groundplane[1];
  shadowMat[2][3] = 0.f - lightpos[3] * groundplane[2];
  shadowMat[3][3] = dot - lightpos[3] * groundplane[3];

}

enum {X, Y, Z};
enum {A, B, C, D};
/* find the plane equation given 3 points */
void
findplane(GLfloat plane[4],
          GLfloat v0[3], GLfloat v1[3], GLfloat v2[3])
{
  GLfloat vec0[3], vec1[3];

  /* need 2 vectors to find cross product */
  vec0[X] = v1[X] - v0[X];
  vec0[Y] = v1[Y] - v0[Y];
  vec0[Z] = v1[Z] - v0[Z];

  vec1[X] = v2[X] - v0[X];
  vec1[Y] = v2[Y] - v0[Y];
  vec1[Z] = v2[Z] - v0[Z];

  /* find cross product to get A, B, and C of plane equation */
  plane[A] = vec0[Y] * vec1[Z] - vec0[Z] * vec1[Y];
  plane[B] = -(vec0[X] * vec1[Z] - vec0[Z] * vec1[X]);
  plane[C] = vec0[X] * vec1[Y] - vec0[Y] * vec1[X];

  plane[D] = -(plane[A] * v0[X] + plane[B] * v0[Y] + plane[C] * v0[Z]);
}

void sphere(void)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(60.f, -50.f, -360.f);
    glCallList(SPHERE);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void cone(void)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-40.f, -40.f, -400.f);
    glCallList(CONE);
    glPopMatrix();

}

enum {NONE, SHADOW};

int rendermode = NONE;

void menu(int mode)
{
  rendermode = mode;
  glutPostRedisplay();
}


void loadTextureFromFile(char *filename)
{   
   glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   RgbImage theTexMap( filename );  
    glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);                  // Create The Texture
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

        // Typical Texture Generation Using Data From The Bitmap

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, theTexMap.GetNumCols(), theTexMap.GetNumRows(), 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, theTexMap.ImageData() );

}



GLfloat leftwallshadow[4][4];
GLfloat floorshadow[4][4];

GLfloat lightpos[] = {50.f, 50.f, -320.f, 1.f};


/* render while jittering the shadows */
void render(GLfloat dx, GLfloat dy, GLfloat dz)
{

    /* material properties for objects in scene */
    static GLfloat wall_mat[] = {1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f};
    static GLfloat sphere_mat[] = {1.f, .5f, 0.f, 1.f};
    static GLfloat cone_mat[] = {0.f, .5f, 1.f, 1.f};

    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    /*
    ** Note: wall verticies are ordered so they are all front facing
    ** this lets me do back face culling to speed things up.
    */

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, wall_mat);

        /* floor */
    /* make the floor textured */
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    /*
    ** Since we want to turn texturing on for floor only, we have to
    ** make floor a separate glBegin()/glEnd() sequence. You can't
    ** turn texturing on and off between begin and end calls
    */
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glNormal3f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 0);
    glVertex3f(-100.f, -100.f, -320.f);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 0);
    glVertex3f( 100.f, -100.f, -320.f);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 1);
    glVertex3f( 100.f, -100.f, -520.f);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 1);
    glVertex3f(-100.f, -100.f, -520.f);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);



    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 0.f); /* shadow color */

    glPushMatrix();
    glMultMatrixf((GLfloat *)floorshadow);
    glTranslatef(dx, dy, dz);
    cone();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glMultMatrixf((GLfloat *)floorshadow);
    glTranslatef(dx, dy, dz);
    sphere();
    glPopMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    /* walls */


    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0);
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    /* left wall */
    glNormal3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    glVertex3f(-100.f, -100.f, -320.f);
    glVertex3f(-100.f, -100.f, -520.f);
    glVertex3f(-100.f,  100.f, -520.f);
    glVertex3f(-100.f,  100.f, -320.f);
    glEnd();

    glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 1);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 0.f); /* shadow color */
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glPushMatrix();
    glMultMatrixf((GLfloat *)leftwallshadow);
    glTranslatef(dx, dy, dz);
    cone();
    glPopMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);


    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    /* right wall */
    glNormal3f(-1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    glVertex3f( 100.f, -100.f, -320.f);
    glVertex3f( 100.f,  100.f, -320.f);
    glVertex3f( 100.f,  100.f, -520.f);
    glVertex3f( 100.f, -100.f, -520.f);

    /* ceiling */
    glNormal3f(0.f, -1.f, 0.f);
    glVertex3f(-100.f,  100.f, -320.f);
    glVertex3f(-100.f,  100.f, -520.f);
    glVertex3f( 100.f,  100.f, -520.f);
    glVertex3f( 100.f,  100.f, -320.f);

    /* back wall */
    glNormal3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glVertex3f(-100.f, -100.f, -520.f);
    glVertex3f( 100.f, -100.f, -520.f);
    glVertex3f( 100.f,  100.f, -520.f);
    glVertex3f(-100.f,  100.f, -520.f);
    glEnd();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(lightpos[X], lightpos[Y], lightpos[Z]);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glColor3f(1.f, 1.f, .7f);
    glCallList(LIGHT);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glPopMatrix();


    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, cone_mat);
    cone();

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, sphere_mat);
    sphere();

}

void redraw(void)
{
  int dx, dy, dz;

  dy = 0;
  /* jitter the light around */
  if(rendermode == SHADOW) {
    glClear(GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT);
    for(dz = -4; dz < 5; dz += 2) {
      for(dx = -4; dx < 5; dx += 2) {
        render((GLfloat)dx, (GLfloat)dy, (GLfloat)dz);
        glAccum(GL_ACCUM, 1.f/25);
      }
    }
    glAccum(GL_RETURN, 1.f);
  } else
    render(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);

  glFinish();
  glutSwapBuffers();
}

void key(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if(key == '\033')
        exit(0);
}



const int TEXDIM = 256;
/* Parse arguments, and set up interface between OpenGL and window system */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GLfloat *tex;
    GLUquadricObj *sphere, *cone, *base;
    GLfloat plane[4];
    GLfloat v0[3], v1[3], v2[3];

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_DEPTH|GLUT_STENCIL|GLUT_SINGLE);
    (void)glutCreateWindow("soft shadows");
    glutDisplayFunc(redraw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(key);

    glutCreateMenu(menu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Hard Shadow", NONE);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Soft Shadow", SHADOW);
    glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);


    /* draw a perspective scene */
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glFrustum(-100., 100., -100., 100., 320., 640.); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    /* make shadow matricies */

      /* 3 points on floor */
      v0[X] = -100.f; v0[Y] = -100.f; v0[Z] = -320.f;
      v1[X] =  100.f; v1[Y] = -100.f; v1[Z] = -320.f;
      v2[X] =  100.f; v2[Y] = -100.f; v2[Z] = -520.f;

      findplane(plane, v0, v1, v2);
      shadowmatrix(floorshadow, plane, lightpos);

      /* 3 points on left wall */
      v0[X] = -100.f; v0[Y] = -100.f; v0[Z] = -320.f;
      v1[X] = -100.f; v1[Y] = -100.f; v1[Z] = -520.f;
      v2[X] = -100.f; v2[Y] =  100.f; v2[Z] = -520.f;

      findplane(plane, v0, v1, v2);
      shadowmatrix(leftwallshadow, plane, lightpos);

    /* turn on features */
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    /* place light 0 in the right place */
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightpos);

    /* remove back faces to speed things up */
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    /* make display lists for sphere and cone; for efficiency */

    glNewList(SPHERE, GL_COMPILE);
    sphere = gluNewQuadric();
    gluSphere(sphere, 20.f, 20, 20);
    gluDeleteQuadric(sphere);
    glEndList();


    glNewList(LIGHT, GL_COMPILE);
    sphere = gluNewQuadric();
    gluSphere(sphere, 5.f, 20, 20);
    gluDeleteQuadric(sphere);
    glEndList();

    glNewList(CONE, GL_COMPILE);
    cone = gluNewQuadric();
    base = gluNewQuadric();
    glRotatef(-90.f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    gluDisk(base, 0., 20., 20, 1);
    gluCylinder(cone, 20., 0., 60., 20, 20);
    gluDeleteQuadric(cone);
    gluDeleteQuadric(base);
    glEndList();

    glNewList(FLOOR, GL_COMPILE);
    glEndList();

    glNewList(LEFTWALL, GL_COMPILE);
    glEndList();

    /* load pattern for current 2d texture */
    tex = make_texture(TEXDIM, TEXDIM);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 1, TEXDIM, TEXDIM, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, tex);
    free(tex);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RgbImage` is not a built-in class, so you must add an appropriate `#include` at the top of the file. You'll also need to link to the library containing it if you aren't already doing so.

As far as I can tell, the `RgbImage` class is part of [the `TextureBMP` example](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/MathCG/OpenGLsoft/TextureBMP/TextureBMP.html) accompanying the book "3D Computer Graphics:
A Mathematical Introduction with OpenGL" by Samuel R. Buss. You can download `RgbImage.cpp` and `RgbImage.h` there. You can then include `RgbImage.cpp` into your project and add `#include "RgbImage.h"` to the rest of the includes at the top of the file.